# Get real client IP in OpenShift?

Tags: http, ip, openshift, tornado

I tried [an application](https://github.com/abdelouahabb/hafhafi/), and I used a way to ban those who send more than 5 empty requests to the server, but the problem then, is that everybody got blocked, and this is because everybody was seen as a ONE UNIQUE IP.

[In the code](https://github.com/abdelouahabb/hafhafi/blob/master/handlers.py#L24), I used the way to get the `X-Real-IP` but it doesent work on OpenShift, so how to do that then?

Here is how I get the IP:

```
x_real_ip = self.request.headers.get("X-Real-IP")            
remote_ip = self.request.remote_ip if not x_real_ip else x_real_ip
```

Update: I get `'127.3.165.129', None)` when doing `print(self.request.remote_ip,  x_real_ip)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look for the "x-forwarded-for" header to get the visitors ip address.  What you are seeing is the ip address of the reverse proxy that users go through before ending up at your application/gear.

You can refer to this article in the Developer Center for more information about how requests are routed on OpenShift: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html

Comment: It also might be worth reviewing this article in the Developer Center: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html

Comment: it dident worked as the docs says, putting 8080 will not work, I changed them as vars: `ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])`

Comment: Tornado will recognize the `x-forwarded-for` header if you pass `xheaders=True` when constructing the `HTTPServer`.